# Ever try to delete files with unix shell find? Use the -delete option

Tags: shell, unix, find, command

This has come up a number of times in posts, so I'm mentioning it as a thankyou to all helpful people on stackoverflow.

Have you ever wanted to do a bunch of deletes from the command line/terminal in Unix?  Perhaps you used a construct like

```
find . -name '*.pyc' -exec rm {} \;
```

Look to the answer for an elegant way to do this.

Comment: You should separate this into a question and an answer.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/

Comment: Also, please add that a dry run is necessary. find can find stuff you didn't know you had.

Comment: Not only do users here answer questions, they help newbies get better at using the site! Thanks, gnetlemen! I have edited the original post after looking at the reference made by @SLaks

Comment: You're welcome! See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's how to do it with the `-delete` option!

Use the find command option `-delete`:

```
find . -name '*.pyc' -delete
```

Of course, do try a dry run without the `-delete`, to see if you are going to delete what you want!!! Those computers do run so darn fast! ;-)

Comment: If you do a dry run without the `-delete` flag, when you're ready to delete, *make sure you add the flag to the **end!*** Otherwise, the filter flags that come after it may be ignored.

Answer (score 6):

+1 for taking the initiative and finding the solution to your issue yourself.  A couple of rather minor notes:

I would recommend getting into the habit of using the `-type f` flag when you're wanting to delete files.  This restricts `find` to files that are actually files (i.e. not directories or links).  Otherwise you might inadvertently delete a directory, which is probably *not* what you wanted to do.  (That said, unless you have a directory named 'something.pyc', that wouldn't be an issue for your example command.  It's just a good habit in general.)

Also, just to let you know, if you decide use the `-exec rm..` version, it would run faster if you did this instead:

```
find . -type f -name '*.pyc' -exec rm {} \+
```

This version adds as many arguments to a single invokation of `rm` as it can, thereby reducing the total number of calls to `rm`.  It works pretty much like the default behavior in `xargs`.